# Checkmarx Integration in Gitlab Continuous Integration

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, checkmarx

Is it possible to integrate Checkmarx Static Application Security Testing (SAST) tool into Gitlab Continuous Integration (CI) Pipeline for static security scanning?

Answer (score 3):

I have been using Checkmarx with TeamCity and Jenkins pipeline with their Plugin. However, for GitLab pipeline, we need to use REST APIs/ CLI. I would prefer using CLI over REST APIs as CLI provides more functionality that can be used for pipeline decisions.

You can check their Wiki-
https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KC/pages/5767170/CxSAST+API+Guide
https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KC/pages/52560015/CxConsole+CxSAST+CLI

You can always raise a support ticket for getting the recommended approach by Checkmarx.

Answer (score 1):

For now, no, Checkmarx don't have a special plugin for GitLab integration, but they have really good article how-to enable and configure integration:

https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SD/pages/1929937052/GitLab+Integration

Answer (score 0):

I choose free style rather then going for pipeline job in jenkins.
Here is how I configured even without checkmarx plugin.

First generate a token using below command
runCxConsole.cmd GenerateToken -v -CxUser username -CxPassword admin -CxServer http://localhost

Congfiure below lines of code in Build --> Execute Shell

```
Jenkins Script 
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
export CHECKMARX_HOME=/<checkmarx plugin path>/CxConsolePlugin-8.90.2
echo ${WORKSPACE}
echo $CX_PROJECT_NAME
mkdir ${WORKSPACE}/cxReports
export CHECKMARX_REPORTS_HOME=${WORKSPACE}/cxReports
echo $CHECKMARX_REPORTS_HOME

$CHECKMARX_HOME/runCxConsole.sh Scan -v -CxServer <checkmarx server details> -ProjectName "<project anme>" -cxToken <token> -locationtype folder -locationpath "${WORKSPACE}" -preset "Default Checkamrx" -reportcsv $CHECKMARX_REPORTS_HOME/$CX_PROJECT_NAME.csv -ReportPDF $CHECKMARX_REPORTS_HOME/$CX_PROJECT_NAME.pdf
```

Note:Always use token for authentication with the server instead hard coding the username and password in the CLI command.

For more information you can visit https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SD/pages/222232891/Authentication+Login+to+the+CLI
https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SD/pages/1929937052/GitLab+Integration